# testing database results to set a checkbox as checked

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I want to output a `checked` attribute on my checkboxes if the data appears in my database.

i tried doing `in_array()` but it didn't work because of the values (see Database)

I don't know how i should output them nicely

PHP CODE:

```
    $general_list = "";
if($row['f_general'] == 'Bar, '){
    $general_list .= "<label class=\"bg-danger\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Bar, \" checked=\"checked\"/>Bar</label>";
}else{
    $general_list .= "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Bar, \"/>Bar,</label>";
 } 
if($row['f_general'] == 'Restaurant,'){
    $general_list .= "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Restaurant, \" checked=\"checked\"/>Restaurant,</label>";
}else{
    $general_list .= "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Restaurant, \"/>Restaurant,</label>";
 } 
if($row['f_general'] == 'Coffee Shop,'){
    $general_list .= "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Coffee Shop, \" checked=\"checked\"/>Coffee Shop,</label>";
}else{
    $general_list .= "<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"general[]\" value=\"Coffee Shop, \"/>Coffee Shop,</label>";
 }
```

My database values are stored like this:

```
Bar, Restaurant, Coffee Shop, Concierge,
```

HTML CODE:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Bar, "/>Bar,</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Restaurant, "/>Restaurant,</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Coffee Shop, "/>Coffee Shop,</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Concierge, "/>Concierge,</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Business Center, "/>Business Center,</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="general[]" value="Salon, "/>Salon,</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how your data is coming out of the database, but if you are storing it as a comma-separated string: don't. There are better ways to do it--use separate database rows for each of the entities in `$row['f_general']`, i.e.

```
f_general
Bar
Restaurant
Coffee Shop
(etc.)
```

You can then do a query and put all the items in the field `f_general` into an array, rather than having to parse a comma-separated string.

Since you do have the string, parse it to create an array:

```
$db_row = explode(", ", $row['f_general']);
```

You can then make your code a lot more compact and easy to maintain by doing the following:

```
# set up an array with all the checkboxes in it:
$items = array('Bar', 'Restaurant', 'Coffee Shop', 'Concierge', 'Business Center', 'Salon');

$general_list = '';

# go through each item in the array
foreach ($items as $i) {
    # see if that item is in the data from the database
    if ( in_array($i, $db_row) ) {
        $general_list .= '<label class="bg-danger"><input type="radio" name="general[]" value="'
        . $i . '" checked="checked" />' . $i . '</label>';
    }
    else {
        $general_list .= '<label><input type="radio" name="general[]" value="'
        . $i . '" />' . $i . '</label>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea on how it should be done. finally understood

Answer (score 0):

Don't add comma with value.You can use implode to store value like

```
implode(",",$_POST[general]);
```

and explode for display:

```
explode(",",$_POST[general]); //it will return array
```